# Orm class files are missing in propel

Tags: php, propel

I have installed propel in my windows xampp server,but it was not generating orm classes. Inside class folder it does not have "map & Orm" folder while I install.So when I execute the page it returns error that says "Class UserQuery not found". So please suggest me if I miss anything.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a `schema.xml` and, then, build model by running:

```
./generator/bin/propel-gen main
```

(Or `om`, `main` will generate SQL files too)